# what are the advantages and limitations of OFBIZ framework 9?

Tags: ofbiz

I am new to OFBIZ 9.I would like to know what are the advantages and limitations of using OFBIZ ERP based framework.Does anybody having thoughts about this Please share with me...

Thanks & Regards,
SARAVANAN.P

Comment: I can see from your questions, you've been using OFbiz for some time - so what area specifically do you want to know

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess that the version number is not important here. You're just asking for Ofbiz in general, right? I wrote a [blog post](http://marksweep.blogspot.com/2011/09/broadleaf-commerce-vs-apache-ofbiz.html) about how time consuming it is to start with Apache Ofbiz in comparison with [Broadleaf Commerce](http://www.broadleafcommerce.org/). I cannot talk about the other components that the shopping cart itself, because I didn't need almost any of them.

The advantage is, that after you spend the time learning and investigating the engine and develop a production ready shopping cart. It is not so hard to change / modify it to come up with another custom cart. And if you anytime need an advanced components like promotions, accounting (billing, invoicing), CMS or CRM, you will be ready to add them.

The disadvantage is, that the framework is good for truly custom development for rather medium and big businesses. It's not like that you would come up with a SaaS where you would rent shopping carts that suits needs of small businesses. The entity model and administration is flexible, but the one who makes the changes is the developer. The developer adds/changes groovy scripts that define the product etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working for about a month with ofbiz. And I've found it to be very difficult to follow and understand because of the lack of online resources.

The official documentation is outdated, in http://www.stackoverflow.com I have not found many questions and answers to the issues I've had when working on ofbiz and I haven't found recent books on ofbiz either. The only place that really helped me understand ofbiz has been HotWax University http://www.hotwaxsystems.com/company-news/hotwax-university/

I do appreciate that big parts of the logic that you'd have to implement are already implemented. But, imho, given it's so big and complex, you have to have a very good knowledge of how to build an ERP before you feel comfortable with ofbiz.

Answer (score 0):

Today there are some books and many tutorials to learn functionalty:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/OFBiz+Related+Books

As a user you could just download and run OFBiz to explore the interface
and e.g. the ecommerce application.

As developer you could read a startup tutorial:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/OFBiz+Tutorial+-+A+Beginners+Development+Guide

To understand the data model and the overall functionality of
OFBiz you could read the Data Model Ressource Book,
which gives an excellent explanation of the 
basis, on which OFBiz operates.

This question has not been posted yesterday, but the answer about 7 years
later could be: there is anupdated documentation and in Version 16 some important simplifications (e.g. from minilang and java to groovy), so it seems worth exploring OFBiz from a todays perspective.